# Saving image in the database not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cross-browser

I am trying to create a cross platform application and I would like to save images from different devices in the database using Codeigiter. I am able to select the images form the device but I am confused and stocked on how to save images and retrieving them from the database.

Controller

```
function addstatesoothing() {

    // write user data into the user database
    $config['upload_path'] = './';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000000';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $image_path = $this->upload->data('soothing-img');
    $data = array(
        'soothing-img' => $image_path[full_path],
        'soothing-title' => $this->input->post('soothing-title'),
    );
    $this->favourite_db->addstatesoothing($data);
    $this->load->view('soothing');
}
```

Model

```
function addstatesoothing($data) {
    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->insert('soothing', $data);
    return $data;
}
```

View

```
 <form method="post" action="addstatesoothing">
                <!--  <button data-theme="d" onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> -->
                <a data-theme="d" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">Click to Add Pictures</a> 
                <img style="width:100%;" id="largeImage" src="" name="soothing-img"/> <br>
                <input type="text" name="soothing-title" id="Climbed a Mountain" value="" placeholder="Climbed a Mountain"/>
                <button data-theme="a">Save Memory</button>
                </form>
```

Comment: being confused and stocked is not a problem which can be solved over here, so what are your programming issues?

Comment: The code above does not save the image file in the database

Comment: ah, I thought ` $this->db->insert('soothing', $data);` does this, but someone did your homework already ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To save image in database:

1 - Your image field on database should be BLOB type.

2 - Get file content from your image:

```
$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

3 - Save it in your BLOB type field on database

```
mysql_query("insert into images (image) values ('$image') ");
```

I don't know if you use another approach to save data in database, your code is a bit different , but that's the way, right? In the end it'll be a row inserted in database, If you have any doubt, comment here, but at this point is all easy, ham? now let's go to retriving images

First of all, **storing images content in database is a real mistake**, but that isn't the question right? So I'm not an expert in this approach, but is how I would:

Create an another page like image.php, receiving some id or image name  by parameter

**image.php:**

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id']; 
$query = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE `id`=$id";
$result = mysql_query($query);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); //if is another format like .png change here


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['image'];
}
?>
```

Nice, you have a nice *.php file that response an image just like any *.jpg file, so now call it in your HTML

**SomePage.html**:

```
<img src="image.php?id=12345" />
```

Ok, all done,

but **why I told that saving image content is bad?:** SO fellas are awesome, we have amazing material to explain why saving images in database is BAD! You could check it,  here's:

1. [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)
2. [Store images in database or on file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550197/store-images-in-database-or-on-file-system)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing in this question is your form is not able to upload image because your not using multipart form data

you can try like this

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```